# How to change post request to get request in postman?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a request and it was post request earlier but I need to change it to get request.

```
//teamsApi.js
async getTeamsWithPlayers(payload) {
        const response = await this.request('/teams/getPlayers', payload) //post request
        return response
    }

//base.js
import {$api_esports} from '../api'
export class API_BASE_ESPORTS {
    async request(url, payload, config) {
        const response = await $api_esports.post(url, payload, config).then(handleData).catch(handleError)
        return response
    }
}

//api.js
export const $api_esports = axios.create({
    withCredentials: false,
    baseURL: API_ESPORT_URL,
})
```

I tried to add new request to API_BASE_ESPORTS but it didn't work(like this)

```
export class API_BASE_ESPORTS {
    async request(url, payload, config) {
        const response = await $api_esports.post(url, payload, config).then(handleData).catch(handleError)
        return response
    }
    async getRequest(url) {
        const response = await $api_esports.get(url).then(handleData).catch(handleError)
        return response
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to change `const response = await $api_esports.post(` to `const response = await $api_esports.get(`?

Comment: @David, I tried this one, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I haven't overlooked something, axios doesn't allow GET requests with additional payload:

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config (see the `data` property).

This means, you'd have to convert your payload into a URL parameter string, append that to the URL you pass to `API_BASE_ESPORTS.request` and additionally change the `$api_esports.post` call to `$api_esports.get`.